# KiCad footprint for 5 mm three pin potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, kicad, footprint

I want to use a standard three pin through-hole potentiometer in my design.

The pins have a distance of 5 mm between them.

KiCad has literally hundreds of footprints for through-hole potentiometers, however this is a very common component.

Does anyone have an idea of a common footprint to use?

Comment: Copy a nearly-suitable footprint and shift the pin positions to suit your pot.  If you do much PCB layout work, you WILL have to make or modify footprints, so may as well learn how now...  Are you sure the pin spacing is 5.00 mm, and not 5.08 mm (0.2 inch)?

Comment: Can you post the part number?

Comment: @LiorBilia Unfortunately there is no part number visible. I bought it in bulk from a local store, I didn't order it online.

Comment: @PeterBennett The measurement was not accurate as I didn't have a vernier caliper back at home. I pushed the pot pins into a piece of paper in order to pierce it, then brought it at work and measured the distances between the tears of the paper with the vernier caliper. I measured around 5mm. Is the 5.08mm standard in potentiometer pin spacings? Because if it is, this is what it probably is.

Comment: Many electronic components for through-hole PC boards have leads arranged to fit an 0.1 inch (2.54 mm) grid.  If you can find a datasheet for your potentiometer, you should be able to determine the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments above editing an existing component is often the easiest way to go. But if you aren't up to it for any reason there is a simple work-around. Implement a simple multi-pin device using separate pins.

1. Remove the pot from the schematic.
2. In schematic editor select a single pin header connector (or just about any single pin device).
3. Place three of these single pin parts into the schematic where the pot connections would be. (Add more pins if needed, for example mounting pins.)
4. Optionally add graphics, notes, and/or pin names to help keep track of each pin.
5. When you go to PCB editor manually position the pins exactly where you need them.
6. If needed you could edit the pad size, hole size, and even add silkscreen text/graphics for each pin or for the body of the pot.

This is just a quick and non-elegant way of implementing a part without a suitable footprint. You wouldn't want to do this very often as you could easily lose track of things especially if you need to make changes at a later time. You would also have to manually watch for problems like keep-out issues, component clearances, etc. This method can also be used to connect off-board components that may have wire connections coming from awkward positions.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for making a footprint for an unknown through hole device:

1. Measure each pin diameter. The hole for each pin should have an additional +-0.1mm tolerance.
2. Measure the distance between the pins outer sides.
3. Measure the distance between the pins inner sides.
4. Subtract 1 pin diameter from the outer sides measurement. That gives you the pitch.
5. For validation, add 1 pin diameter to the inner side measurement. It should be equal to #4, within your measurement tolerance.
6. If the pins are arranged in a diagonal pattern, you should do steps 2 to 5 in both axis.